# Ativar Hover por javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Olá pessoal é o seguinte:

- Criei um html que contém uma imagem, um texto e um botão;
- A imagem tem um transition que faz a imagem subir até certo ponto;
- O texto tem uma opacidade quando passo o mouse em cima;

O que preciso é que quando clicar no botão as ações da imagem, e do texto sejam executadas e seja mostrado um vídeo no lugar aonde estavam a imagem e o texto.

O html está mais ou menos assim

```
<div class="center-natal">
            <div class="animationNatal">
                <img class="logoNatal" src="img.png" alt="" title="" />
                <h1 class="titNatal">MOMENTOS QUE MARCAM...<br><span>TRADIÇÕES QUE FICAM!</span></h1>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn-assita-natal">ASSISTA AO FILME</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for um elemento distinto, por norma utiliza-se "id" (#), se for um aspecto genérico utiliza-se "class" (.). Se entendi bem a questão, em um caso de esconder/mostrar o vídeo com o clique de um botão:

Então para:

```
<div class="center-natal">
            <div class="animationNatal">
                <img id="logoNatal" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" title="" />
             <video id="vid" src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls>
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
                <h1 id="titNatal">MOMENTOS QUE MARCAM...<br><span>TRADIÇÕES QUE FICAM!</span></h1>
            </div>
            <a id="link"href="#" class="btn-assita-natal">ASSISTA AO FILME</a>
        </div>
```

Em JS puro:

```
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function play(){
  var tit = document.getElementById("titNatal");
  var logo = document.getElementById("logoNatal");
  var vid = document.getElementById("vid");

   if(logo.style.display === 'none')
    {
      logo.style.display = 'block';
      tit.style.display = 'block';
      vid.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
      logo.style.display = 'none';
      tit.style.display = 'none';
      vid.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Aqui está um exemplo: http://codepen.io/tomasMetcalfe/pen/aBZmKG